# Argument 1 passed to Foo::__construct() must be an instance of Psr\Log\LoggerTrait, instance of Mock_Trait_LoggerTrait_65811a25_bdddd884 given

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, traits

I'm trying to mock a simple trait with PHPUnit but it is resulting on a FatalError, it works if I remove the type hinting: Argument 1 passed to Foo::__construct() must be an instance of Psr\Log\LoggerTrait, instance of Mock_Trait_LoggerTrait_65811a25_bdddd884 given

The class:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerTrait;

class Foo {

    /**
     * @var LoggerTrait
    */
    private $mLogger;

    public function __construct(LoggerTrait $iLogger)
    {
        $this->mLogger = $iLogger;
    }
}
```

The test:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testRun ()
    {
        $logger = $this->getMockForTrait('\Psr\Log\LoggerTrait');

        $sut = new Foo($logger);
    }
}
```

How I should solve this?

Comment: *How I should solve this?* Pass an instance from the class `LoggerTrait` to the constructor ?!

Comment: I've found it to be tricky too. If you do a var_dump($logger); after yoiur getMockForTrait, is it an object of type "LoggerTrait". You definitely don't want to remove your type hint. That would suck. One way I've solved this is to create a stub Trait in a test helper and then give that to getMockForTrait. Sucks, but works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't type hint traits.  Your type hint is looking for a class of type `\Psr\Log\LoggerTrait`.  It appears that it is actually a trait and not an object.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

The getMockForTrait method is used to create a concrete object of the trait so that you can test the traits functionality.  It creates an object that uses the traits methods with any abstract methods being mocked.  It doesn't extend the trait so the type hint is invalid.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes

You seem to be misusing traits for what you are looking to do.  A trait is PHP's way of allowing classes to share functionality without needing to extend each other.  Traits cannot be instantiated, they would be used to share functionality between otherwise unrelated objects.

Your "trait" should just be a class that you pass in.  And your test would then become:

```
public function testRun ()
{
    $logger = $this->getMock('\Psr\Log\Logger');  //Changed name to not be Trait

    $sut = new Foo($logger);
}
```